# pyqtgraph: copy and remove a graphics item

Tags: python, copy-paste, pyqtgraph, qgraphicsitem

I want to copy or remove a graphic item by right clicking on the item and use the context menu to do it. I have no problem removing the item by using scene().removeItem(self), but i can't make a new copy (or add any kind of graphic item) to the scene by using scene().addItem(). The source code is below, the core problem appears in self_copy function. So what should I do to make a new copy?

```
import numpy as np

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMenu

class TestLine(pg.InfiniteLine):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.movable = True

    def raiseContextMenu(self, ev):
        context = QMenu()
        context.addAction("remove", self.self_remove)
        context.addAction("copy", self.self_copy)
        pos = ev.screenPos()
        context.exec(QtCore.QPoint(int(pos.x()), int(pos.y())))

    def self_copy(self):
        self.scene().addItem(self) # It doesn't work.
        #self.parentItem().addItem(self)    #It doesn't work either.
        
    def self_remove(self):
        self.scene().removeItem(self)
        
    def mouseClickEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            self.raiseContextMenu(ev)
            ev.accept()


app = pg.mkQApp("InfiniteLine Example")
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="Plotting items examples")
win.resize(1000,600)

# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

# Create a plot with some random data
p1 = win.addPlot(title="Plot Items example", y=np.random.normal(size=100, scale=10), pen=0.5)
p1.setYRange(-40, 40)

test = TestLine(pos=(10, 10), angle=45)

p1.addItem(test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

I also tried self.parentItem().addItem(), but it doens't work either.